# ECS events with Custom event bus rule not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-event-bridge

I have an ECS task and I want to trigger a Lambda function once ECS task stopped. I created an event rule like below

```
    {
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail-type": ["ECS Task State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": ["arn:aws:ecs:region:account:cluster/mycluster"],
    "taskDefinitionArn": ["arn:aws:ecs:region:account:task-definition/mytaskdefinition:revisionNumber"],
    "lastStatus": ["STOPPED"]
  }
}
```

This rule worked perfect when I used Default event bus, but as soon as I moved this event rule to a Custom Event bus, no events coming to that rule.

Comment: How are the events getting to your custom bus?

Comment: @gshpychka ECS events can emit the events to event bus? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Events are emitted only to the default event bus. If you want to have them in a different event bus that you created, you need to create a Rule that forwards them there.

You would do this by creating a [`Rule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html#addwbrtargettarget) in your default event bus and use [`events_targets.EventBus`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events_targets.EventBus.html) as the target to forward them to your custom event bus.

After you do this, you can create rules in the custom event bus to handle the events being forwarded there.